# React - onClick(item) of item in list using for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, onclick

I am making a react list, whose items should trigger an action to update state.
Both the triggering and the state update occur, however, **the onClick method is calling the action with the same argument every time**. This should not occur. The argument passed to the action must depend on the item of the list clicked.

I can not seam to find the bug that is causing this error.

This is my dropdown class, where the list is rendered.

```html
class DropDownMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render(){
    let content = []
    var categories = this.props.categories
    for (var i=0; i < categories.length; i++) {
      var catName = categories[i]
      var line = (
        <li
          key ={i}
          onClick = {() => {this.props.onClick(catName)}}
        >
        <p>{catName}</p>
        </li>
      )
      content.push(line)
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown ref="dropdown">
          <DropdownTrigger>Categories</DropdownTrigger>
          <DropdownContent>
            <ul>
              { content }
            </ul>
          </DropdownContent>
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the container that manages the state and calls the above class

```html
class MenuContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <a onClick = {() => {this.props.changeView("main")}}>back</a>
          <a onClick = {() => {this.props.changeView("shoppingCart ")}}>my cart</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <DropDownMenu
            categories = {this.props.categories}
            onClick = {(catName) => {this.props.selectCategory(catName)}}
          />
          <ItemList
            items = {this.props.items}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    categories: getCategories(state),
    items: getItems(state)
  }
}

const mapDispathToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    changeView: (view) => {
      dispatch(setView(view))
    },
    selectCategory: (catName) => {
      dispatch(setCategory(catName))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispathToProps)(MenuContainer)
```

```
I reducer the error to the line:

   for (var i=0; i < categories.length; i++) {
      var catName = categories[i]
      var line = (
        <li
          key ={i}
          onClick = {() => {this.props.onClick(catName)}}
        >
        <p>{catName}</p>
```

I replaced this.props.onClick with console log of the catName, and it always logs the same, althoug it correctly shows the items in the

tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `for` loop does not form a `closure`. Better use a map function like this

```
let content = categories.map((catName, i) => {
      return (
        <li
          key ={i}
          onClick = {() => {this.props.onClick(catName)}}
        >
        <p>{catName}</p>
        </li>
      )
    });
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. just a follow up question, how can i pass a unique ID to the <li> tag, since the {i} from the for function is gone.

Comment: Map still provides the index as the second argument in your function. although using the index as a key is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @RafaelMarques No its not gone. Second argument of map calback is index. Check updated answer

Comment: perfect, thank you. will mark this as answered in 4 minutes (allowed time)

Comment: Just a quick comment: Using the index as a key isn't _always_ a bad idea. If the items in the list are guaranteed to not change their order, then using the index is fine. Otherwise, you will want to use a unique identifier for each record being mapped.